# 2018 MPB - Bootcamp - windows setup failing for unclear reason

Tags: bootcamp

This is very frustrating & I've tried multiple ways to troubleshoot it including:

- Resetting PRAM
- Disk Utility first aid
- Choosing different partition sizes

My MBP runs the latest Monterey release 12.5.1.
Bootcamp runs normally and partitions my drive successfully, once my MacBook reboots into the Windows setup screen and initiates setup (after agreeing to the TOS and hitting the final "next" - where it starts to "copy files"), this message comes up
[image]

I googled the heck out of this error code & couldn't nail it down. I'm fairly eloquent with tech but this is just beyond me. The last resort I have right now is to clean-install macOS, but I worry that I'm gonna waste all this time backing-up & restoring my personal files just to end up with the same results.

Much appreciated in advance!

Comment: Which version of Windows are you trying to install? Might be helpful to see the output from the macOS command `diskutil list` right after Windows installation fails.

Comment: @DavidAnderson excuse my ignorance but how can I run this command from Windows setup? This photo / case in outside macOS environment. Trying to install Windows 10 Home, but I tried other versions too.

Comment: I assume you would boot back to Monterey, then execute the command.

Comment: will try it out and update you! thanks!